# How to stop Google from sending updates about places in your lists?

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps wouldn't stop pestering me about updates about the places I saved in my "Wants to go" list, so I had to ditch the list entirely and instead save those places in a "Foobar" list.

Now Google is doing the same with places in my "Favorites" list.

It also tried doing the same with the city I live and the city I work in, but at least for these it's possible to opt out.

Is there a way to stop this kind of annoying behaviour?

Comment: any screenshot examples?

Comment: Not available right now, but I'll post one as soon as Google suggests something again. These suggestions come as Maps notifications on my phone.